# Mongoose: Cast to array of object failed for value [{"someKey": "someValue"}]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting error whenever I'm trying to save into my database a document with this schema:

```
var schemaForBooks = new Schema({
    book: String,
    author: String,
    who_has_this: Object,
    points: Number,
    upvoted_by_users: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    downvoted_by_users: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]
});
```

Rest all is good, but putting anything into `upvoted_by_users` or `downvoted_by_users`, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Trace- CastError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[{"userName":"Vibhu","userId":"3833d1g870feaf4a38723"}]" at path "upvoted_
by_users"
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with the schema itself, but I don't know what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: {"userName":"Vibhu","userId":"3833d1g870feaf4a38723"}, is this what you're placing in the array?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do that, but now I know, I'll have to create a nested Schema for that. I was too dumb here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you're trying to cast the following array of object `{"userName":"Vibhu", "userId":"3833d1g870feaf4a38723"}` to an array of `ObjectId`.

So, you need to get rid of the `userName` field, so you can turn your array of `String` + `ObjectId` to an array of `ObjectId`.

You can do it with the `Array#map` method on your js Array, for example :

```
var arr = [{"userName":"Vibhu","userId":"3833d1g870feaf4a38723"}];
var myCorrectArr = arr.map(field => field.userId);
```

Hope it helps,
Best regards,

Comment: Thanks @boehm_s, your reply didn't directly answered my query but got  me to that. I was confusing `ObjectId` with some generic `Object` object